# primefaces, how to conditionally render a component without creating it

Tags: jsf, primefaces, rendering

I work with primefaces 3.4.1 and myfaces 2.1.9.

I need to show a component within a tab conditionally.
For the moment my code looks like that :

```
<p:tab id="tab" title="tabTitle">
     <h:panelGroup id="tabContent">
        <componentX:component id="component1" rendered="#{not condition}" />
        <componentY:component id="component2" rendered="#{condition}" />
     </h:panelGroup>
 </p:tab>
```

I voluntarily changed the name of the components and arguments

My problem is with this solution component1 and component2 are both created. So the server will be working to generate the two components event if one is never shown.

My question is, is there a (clean) way to have this rendering result without creating both components?
I had the same results with c:if and c:choose, I am running out of ideas.

Comment: I think some redesign is needed, there is nothing wrong in creating a component , just make sure that no heavy logic is done inside it if there is no need , Or your can create some controller bean that will decide if there is a need to create some component or not

Comment: The `<c:if>` and `<c:choose>` should do it. Please describe the concrete problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use c:if here without problems...